# ARM NEON Intrisics support in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, arm, neon

What is the earliest version of Visual Studio (C++) that supports the ARM NEON Intrinsics, if any ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 supports NEON intrinsics (as well as ARMv6 intrinsics) when compiling for Windows-on-ARM. Visual Studio 2008 supported only ARMv5 DSP, XScale, and WMMX instructions when compiling for Windows Mobile.