# Selecting a Windows Compact 7 compiler with VFP/Neon support

Tags: neon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using VFP/Neon for a Visual Studio 2008 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639940/using-vfp-neon-for-a-visual-studio-2008-application)

I have built a Windows Compact 7 OS image and SDK with the Platform Builder plugin for Visual Studio 2008. I know that Visual Studio 2008 supports neither VFP nor NEON.

So, which compiler shoud I use to develop a C/C++ application for Windows Compact 7 using VFP/Neon co-processors?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 should work, according to [ARM NEON Intrisics support in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839780).

I doubt that you have any choice but to stick with MSVC - Clang and GCC both have limited ABI-compatibility MSVC even on x86 and x86-64, so I'd be very surprised if they are compatible on ARM.